# How to load xib of a viewcontrolller from a custom method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my three 20 project i am calling and sending some parameters to a method of my view controller using map object. I am passing the image name through parameter to my view controller. I have bound a xib file with my view controller . my xib contains a toolbar at the top and uiimage view. My problem is that when i pass parameter to my custom method and load my xib file in the next line then my view controller's view is not displayed on the screen. I am receiving the parameter in my custom method but unable to load xib on the screen. 
I am using the following custom method

```
-(void)loadImageWithName:(NSString *)img
{
    PhotoView *vw = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoView" bundle:nil];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
    [vw.drawImage setImage:tempImage]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:vw animated:YES];
}
```

When i do this i can see my xib loaded on the window.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

     TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = _window;

    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://photo" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://photo"]];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But when i do this my xib does not load and i see only a white screen

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

    TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = _window;

    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://photo/(loadImageWithName:)" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://photo/myphoto.png"]];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This is the issue that i am facing right now.

I solved the above issue by using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

     TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = _window;

    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://photo/detail?name=(initWithImage:)" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tt://photo/detail?name=%@",@"level_me_up_small.png"]]];

    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But still there are two probe.

1. i am getting extra space between my toolbar at top and uiimageview.

2.UIImageView image is not changed to instant_poetry_small.png.

Comment: Now i loaded my xib by using following -(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
    //NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([img class]));
    PhotoView *vw = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoView" bundle:nil];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instant_poetry_small.png" ];
    [vw.drawImage setImage:tempImage]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:vw animated:YES];
    return self;
}

Comment: But still there are two probe.  1. i am getting extra space between my toolbar at top and uiimageview.  2.UIImageView image is not changed to instant_poetry_small.png.

Comment: Is the NIB file at least loaded ? Could you log `vw` to see if it's a valid reference ? If none of what you tried work, you might have a problem with the file name, or the NIB file isn't included in the app bundle

Comment: My Nib file is loading. But there is some white space between toolbar and uiimageview at run time.

Comment: This works for me                                                   -(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instant_poetry_small.png" ];
    drawImage.image = tempImage;
  }
 

-(id)initWithImage:(NSString *)img{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    return self;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it will help, but try this:

```
vw.drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:tempImage];
```

instead of

```
[vw.drawImage setImage:tempImage];
```

the rest of the code looks OK for me

Comment: my loadImageWithName method is in my PhotoView class and i am sure that it is running but it is not able to load the xib. What can be the reason? Can you tell me?

Comment: Suppose i have a xib which has one UIImageView and one Toolbar. I am loading my xib file from initWithNibName and at the next line i have written the code to change the image of UIImageView. Is there any problem? i want change the image of UIImageView but it is showing me the image that i have attached with UIImageView at interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the drawImage to UIImageView in the xib file ?, May be you wouldn't have linked it using Interface Builder

Comment: I have linked UIImageView with drawImage.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];
    
     TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.window = _window;
    
    TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
    [map from:@"tt://photo" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://photo"]];
    
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Instead of [map from:@"tt://photo/(loadImageWithName:)" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]]; try [map from:@"tt://photo/(loadImageWithName:)
" toViewController:[PhotoView class]];

Comment: Now i am using [map from:@"tt://photo/detail?name=(initWithImage:)" toSharedViewController:[PhotoView class]]; and its working fine. i have commented two more issues. can you please help me in that probs?

Comment: Suppose i have a xib which has one UIImageView and one Toolbar. I am loading my xib file from initWithNibName and at the next line i have written the code to change the image of UIImageView. Is there any problem? i want change the image of UIImageView but it is showing me the image that i have attached with UIImageView at interface builder.